# Lightweight application to send files via browser with http

Tags: linux, files, apache-httpd

I have a server allowing traffic only on port 80 and 443.
I need to upload a file to said server.

Isn't there any application allowing me to upload a file to a server folder via browser?I have apache installed and I have no problem adding php, I would just need to open the browser, drag/drop or select a file on my pc, and send that file to a specific folder of the server.

Comment: I would recommend that you install `openssh-server` in your server. Then you can use `sftp` or `rsync` to transfer files in both directions between the server and a client computer. You can also log in to the server via `ssh` and  run remotely. These are light-weight command line tools.

Comment: So what's preventing you to add a php file to your server that does exactly that? Googling "upload php apache" has plenty of hits. What have you tried, what worked, what didn't work? (And yes, I second installing an ssh demon on your server, it makes life a lot easier).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly certain of your context, but uploading files via web interface / browser can be accomplished using https://www.dropzonejs.com/.

However, you will need some way to configure the server backend... I'm assuming you have a control panel with some kind of file editor?

If not, you have no way of adding the "file upload" application in the first place and this is a nonstarter.